# How do I accept an answer to my questions?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Firstly, I am glad to be here and thankful for the answers that I am getting. But it seems I'm not getting answers anymore because I am oblivious of things that need to be done in order to gain popularity.

In particular, I've been told that I need to "accept more answers", but I don't see a link where one can accept an answer to a question. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: Click the check mark next to the answer you like.

Comment: You cannot accept **questions** - but one of the **ANSWERS** to each of your questions! See that [link labelled FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) link in the top row, just left of the search box?!? Click on it, READ the FAQ - it explains it all

Comment: No one is going to explain this as well as it is covered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @sonx, it's not about popularity, it's about doing things the correct way. People are not as eager to answer if you don't mark the accepted answer (which gives the answerer 15 rep points). You should look to give back more, answer a few questions, and build your own rep as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be a little check mark next to each answer, underneath the vote tally. Just click it and you've accepted the answer.

.

<-- It should be about here.

Answer (score 14):

You should click the check mark to the left of this piece of text :).
[Arrow which points to the check mark http://i54.tinypic.com/adkiuf.gif](http://i54.tinypic.com/adkiuf.gif)

Comment: +1 for the arrow that nobody could miss, it could have been pointing more on an upward angle though.

Comment: I refuse to upvote until I see freehand circles.

Comment: It's a shame that this is no freehand arrow.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I've made an attempt to create my own arrow.

Comment: be fair, sonx can not vote, he has only 8 reputation points when he was writing this question!!

Answer (score 2):

You an vote with the Arrows, BUT

you need some more points (reputation) to be allowed to vote. 
You need 15 reputation points to vote up.

@see [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)