# No check mark – How do I mark an answer as accepted?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, accepted-answer

I recently asked a question and would like to mark one of the answers as accepted. The problem is that I do not see a way to do so. On the left-hand side of the answer I can either vote up/down or view the answer's timeline. Shouldn't there be a check mark as well?

Neither Chrome or Firefox offer an option to check the desired answer as accepted. No plugins are enabled. The checkmark's DOM element is present on the page with CSS styling `display: none !important;`.

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) [several](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) [questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) [relating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91889/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-to-my-questions) to how to accepted an answer, but none of them offered a working solution.

- Do certain communities disable the option to mark answers?
- Do I need a higher reputation to mark an answer as accepted?

I would appreciate any clarity you could offer as I would like to show my appreciation for the user's help.

Comment: Are you sure what you got was an answer post and not a comment?

Comment: Can you add a link to the question and a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek As far I've checked their account, there aren't any visible questions at all.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect there might be another account involved - hence asking for a link :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well *something* [went wrong here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/65002/legal-obligations-of-the-designated-next-of-kin-the-deceased-lived-overseas) - as evidenced by the fact that there are two LegalQuestionGuests and you did an edit as a different user on the question. You're not using the account that created the question, presumably due to cookie shenanigans. It's a good idea to register a user (in spite of your username) to avoid this.

You can use the "Contact" link at the bottom of every page. Do it in the Law site, use the merge profiles option, supply both profiles that were used on that question, and they should be able to associate the post with an account.